# Update Laravel 8 with srlabs/centaur: "11.*" to Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, sentinel

I am upgrading an old application (I did'nt develop it) with srlabs/centaur version 11.*

I am trying to upgrade the laravel version to Laravel 9 but got this error.

```
- srlabs/centaur 11.01.00 requires illuminate/support ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27].
- Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.8, v10.0.0, ..., v10.13.2], laravel/framework[v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.8]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^9.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.8].
```

How to i upgrade this since i saw the Centaur ([github_link](https://github.com/stagerightlabs/Centaur)) is only supported until Laravel 8.

Do i need to change Centaur to Sentinel([github_link](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/6.x)). If i need to change, do i need to rebuild all the custom code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you won't be able to use it on Laravel 9. The latest update of the package only supports Laravel 10. See the code changes between 11.01.00 and 12.0.0 (latest) [here](https://github.com/stagerightlabs/Centaur/compare/11.01.00...12.0.0).